# Google calendar API v3 all day events from before timeMin

Tags: php, timezone, google-calendar-api

I have the following events in my test google calendar:

- All day event on the 20. February
- Timed event on the 21. February from 10am till 11am

I do a request against the Google calendar API with the parameters `timeMin = 2018-02-21T00:00:00+00:00` and `timeMax = 2018-02-21T23:59:59+00:00`. All is working fine when the calendar has the timezone UTC. Only the timed event is returned. But when I set the calendar timezone to something like "(GMT-06:00) Central Time" then the result does include also the all day event.

Is there a way to fetch the events ignoring the timezone for all day events? All day events are not bound to a timezone from my understanding and should not be included at anytime when the timeMin parameter is not from the day of the all day event.

Comment: All-day events effectively start at midnight. So in a way they are bound to the timezone - after all, midnight in one part of the world is not midnight in another part. So if your calendar has a timezone offset but your query parameter doesn't, then yeah your results may not be quite what you expected.

Comment: Aggree with @ADyson, also I think you need to use a valid [`timeZone`](http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zonehelp.tzc). e.g.
 (Europe/Andorra) if I understand it right. You can use [try it](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it) in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) for testing.

Comment: If that would be the case, should then Google not offer for the all day event to set a timezone the same way as with timed events? Even in ics (ical) files you don't define a timezone for all day events. I can't find the link but in barely remember that I was reading somewhere in the past that all day events are not bound to a timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use timeZone param in your query and google will do the needed conversion

> 'timeZone' => 'your time zone'

```
$optParams = array(
        'maxResults' => $maxResults,
        'orderBy' => 'startTime',
        'singleEvents' => TRUE,
        'timeMin' => $timeMin,
        'timeMax' => $timeMax,
        'timeZone' => $timezone
        );
```

Comment: This doesn't help either. The problem is that all day events should not be bound to a timzeone but it looks like Google treats them as 12 am till 12 am of the same day in the timezone of the calendar.